# What does the hand icon indicate, when using Witcher Sense, especially when it appears over tiles in caves?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In *Witcher 3*, sometimes in caves, on top of tiles there appears a hand icon, which can only be seen when using Witcher Sense. It's an open hand with the palm facing downwards.

Anyone know what it means? I've seen these a few times and have tried doing everything I can to interact with them, but nothing works. I hope they aren't important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like the same hand that appears over bee hives, I think it may indicate indirect interaction.

With bee hives you have to use Igni to kill the bees and knock the hive off so you can then interact and get the sweet sweet honeycomb held within.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means to use the spirit lamp

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This is an old question which has already an accepted answer, if you want to post a different answer you should provide sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mark the spot where a portal is supposed to be

Comment: This Steam thread agrees with this guess, but I'm not sure if it's the same symbol: https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/350532795337621113

Comment: If your answer disagrees with other answers, you must back it up with sources. Please edit your post.